# Similar font to Publico and Graphic

Tags: fonts

I have to create a word template for a client from an InDesign document and they want to use a word system font (instead of the fonts I used). Does anyone know a good alternative to "Publico" and "Graphic" (or where I could find such information)?

Comment: Welcome! Can you please add an screenshot of the two used fonts? Assume that not everybody here knows "Publico" and "Graphic" fonts ... And which Word fonts do you have? Can you add a list of this special fonts and the OS you are using?

Comment: Also, can you explain what you mean by "a word system font"?